# Is there a standard for Javascript/jQuery <img /> that haven't yet been placed in the document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a specification for how browsers handle image loading if the image tag is just one of those diembodied Javascript elements that haven't been inserted into the document? An example:

```
$('<img src="/path/to/image.jpg" />')
```

Is there a specification that tells the image to load? I ask because I am interested in the following implementation:

1. Mouseover event on a thumbnail triggers a larger preview image to load.
2. The larger preview image loads and triggers a load event, at which point it is overlaid on top of the original mouseover element.

The implementation of (2) is not hard, but I want to be sure that I can rely on the `load` event across browsers. I have tried it in Firebug and the Chrome console and it seems to work fine, but I haven't encountered a specification telling me that it will always work. I wouldn't put it beyond a browser to refuse to load an image that hasn't been placed in `document`.

Comment: You're creating the `img` element exactly like that? Not `$('<img />')` first, then setting the `src` attribute? Because they route to fundamentally different things (since jQuery 1.4) which may impact the behavior you are asking about.

Comment: Silly me. I've been doing `$("<img />")` in my code, and I thought I'd be all fancy and shorthand on SO. You make a great point though, and I'm definitely going to keep an eye out for when I inevitably make this mistake in the future.

Comment: it seems you have two questions buried in here: 1) does creating a detached `img` element automatically fetch the image's `src` in all browsers? and 2) does the `load` event for an `img` element fire consistently in all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `load` event should fire consistently across modern browsers.  You may have problems with out-dated browsers (pre-IE6).  One thing I must recommend is that you assign a load event handler *before* setting the `src`.  This ensures the event will fire...

```
$("<img />").load(function() {
  alert("Loaded!");
  $(this).css("border", "solid 2px black").appendTo("body");  
}).src("/path/to/image.jpg");
```